# Regular Expression match in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the string `SUM([A2:A10],[B2:B10],[C2:C10],[D2:D10])` and I need to get the elements `[A2:A10],[B2:B10],[C2:C10],[D2:D10]` in an array, so I used `match()` in js. The code snippet is

```
var formula = "SUM([A2:A10],[B2:B10],[C2:C10],[D2:D10])";
var reg = /\[(a-zA-Z0-9)+\]/;
matches = formula.match(reg);
```

But I am not getting the match. I hope the regular expression is wrong. I am very poor in building regular expression. What will be the correct regular expression?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var formula = 'SUM([A2:A10],[B2:B10],[C2:C10],[D2:D10])';
var reg = /\[\w+:\w+\]/g;
matches = formula.match(reg);
```

Output:

```
["[A2:A10]", "[B2:B10]", "[C2:C10]", "[D2:D10]"]
```

Your regex was in the right direction, but didn't include the colon and captured individual characters. The `\w` escape sequence I used is a shortcut for a word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), makes it more readable. The `g` flag is necessary to get all matches instead of just the first one.

Answer (score 3):

```
var formula = "SUM([A2:A10],[B2:B10],[C2:C10],[D2:D10])";
var reg = /\[.*?\]/g;
matches = formula.match(reg);
```

Comment: can you explain the regex /\[.*?\]/g!!

Comment: @JaisonJustus: `.*` basically means 'match anything', and the `?` right after it makes the quantifier lazy so it doesn't match the rest of the input string too, but only up to the next `]`.

Comment: \\[ - pattern starts with [, \\] - pattern ends with ],  . - match any character, * - zero or more, ? - matches each block of []

Comment: I usually prefer a more explicit match, but I like your minimalistic approach. It gets messy once he wants to avoid e.g. empty brackets `"[]"`, when you need to constrain the dot.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "SUM([A2:A10],[B2:B10],[C2:C10],[D2:D10])";

var matches = str.match(/\[[A-Z0-9:]+\]/g);
alert(matches);​
```

Note, you use the `g` flag on the regex to get all the matches.

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aTrLU/

Answer (score 2):

The regex you need is

```
/\[[A-Z][0-9]+:[A-Z][0-9]+\]/gi
```

The g modifier indicates that we should do a global mtching and return all the results, not just the first

The i modifier indicates that we need a case-insensitive matching

An assumption made is that you don't want to include [E2:E10:], because of extra semicolon

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp doesn't include the colon `:`.

Try this: `/\[([0-9A-Z:]+)\]/` , in particular why I have quoted and unquoted square brackets there.

Plus, your input string isn't quoted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot the quotes.
Also, what you need is also the global flag. Here the code:

```
var formula = "SUM([A2:A10],[B2:B10],[C2:C10],[D2:D10])";
var reg = /\[[0-z]+:[0-z]+\]/g;
var matches = formula.match(reg);
```