# Search for specific name onEachFeature

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a function that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function oef(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
        layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name, {
        opacity: 1.00,
        direction: 'top',
        offset: [0, -7]
        });
        }
    }

</script>
```

Now I want to extend that function and search for a specific name in the .geojson file which you can see below:

```
"name": "* Testing",
```

And yes the Asterisk is part of the name. How do I rewrite my function to search for this name and when found the lines on the map that has that name changes color to LightSkyBlue?

Short snippet of my .geojson file:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "_umap_options": {
          "color": "LightSkyBlue",
          "weight": "4",
          "opacity": "1"
        },
        "name": "* Testing",
        "description": "Testing this description..."
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            56.601563,
            -60.930432
          ],
          [
            38.95752,
            -52.629729
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you might have noticed I've made some lines in umap but leaflet does not recognize umap options for color and such so I'm trying to find a workaround.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that I already have a global "colorizer" for the lines that's why I need to search for the name of specific lines.

```
// geoJSON URL'S
var TestlinesURL    = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/***/Testlines.geojson"

// Stuff for lines
var TestlinesStyle = {
"color": "firebrick",
"weight": 5,
"opacity": 0.95
};

// Load .geoJSON
var Testlines       = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX([TestlinesURL],{style:TestlinesStyle,onEachFeature:oef});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to add hardcoded style:

```
function oef(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
        layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name, {
            opacity: 1.00,
            direction: 'top',
            offset: [0, -7]
        });
        
        if(feature.properties.name === "* Testing"){
            layer.setStyle({
                color: "LightSkyBlue"
            })
        }
    }
}
```

But I recommand to readout the umap options:

```
function oef(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
        layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name, {
            opacity: 1.00,
            direction: 'top',
            offset: [0, -7]
        });
        
        if(feature.properties.name === "* Testing"){
            layer.setStyle(feature.properties._umap_options);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah i see, thanks so much for your answer that works!, just one more thing, is it possible to add wildcards in that name search? for example if the properties name is "* Testing Here" or "* Testing 2" that code does not work.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer. The easy way is `if( feature.properties.name.startsWith("* Testing") )` or you can use [RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9901900/8283938)